# Find the value of $C=\frac{6\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}{\cot^2\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)-2\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)+1}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $$C=\dfrac{6\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)}{\cot^2\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{12}\right)-2\tan^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)+1}$$ Here's my approach: $$C=\dfrac{6\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)}{\frac{1+\cos\frac{5\pi}{6}}{1-\cos\frac{5\pi}{6}}-2\cdot\frac{1-\cos\frac{\pi}{6}}{1+\cos\frac{\pi}{6}}+1},$$ using that $\cot^2\alpha=\dfrac{1+\cos2\alpha}{1-\cos2\alpha}$ and $\tan^2\alpha=\dfrac{1-\cos2\alpha}{1+\cos2\alpha}.$ Then $$C=\dfrac{6\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)}{\frac{-1+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+1+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}{1+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}}=\dfrac{6\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)(2+\sqrt3)}{2\sqrt3}$$ Now for $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)$ we have $$\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)=\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)=\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)}{\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)}=\dfrac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{\sqrt6+\sqrt2},$$ using subtraction theorems. Substituting that into $C$, gives $C=\sqrt3$. I doubt that that's the approach that the authors meant for solving the problem. Is there a better one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formulas
$$\cot\frac{5\pi}{12}=\tan\frac{\pi}{12}$$
$$\tan2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}$$
Then
$$C=\dfrac{6\tan\frac{\pi}{12}}{1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{12}}=3\tan\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{3}{\sqrt3}=\sqrt3$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the formula with $x=15=\frac{\pi}{12}$ $$\tan2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}$$ $$\implies \tan30=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}=\frac{2\tan 15}{1-\tan^215}$$
$$\implies \tan^215+2\sqrt3\tan15-1=0$$
$$\implies \tan15=\frac{-2\sqrt3\pm\sqrt{12+4}}{2}$$
Neglect the negative value as $\tan15$ is in first quadrant.

Hence we get $\tan15=2-\sqrt3$ or we get $\cot75=\cot\frac{5\pi}{12}=2-\sqrt3$

Put these values in your expression to obtain the answer $$\boxed{\sqrt3}$$